# TTL not working with custom auth on Squid

Tags: http-proxy, squid

Im currently using Squid 4.10 on a server and have configured a basic authentication script in python and have created the required acl. The authentication from the browser works as intended but does not prompt for the authentication after the time set in `auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 hour`.

My squid.conf:

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
#http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager



include /etc/squid/conf.d/*
auth_param basic program /usr/bin/python3 /etc/squid/squidauth.py
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Enter Username and Password
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 hour
auth_param basic casesensitive on
acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow auth_users
http_access deny all

http_port 3000

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern \/(Packages|Sources)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/Release(|\.gpg)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/InRelease$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern \/(Translation-.*)(|\.bz2|\.gz|\.xz)$ 0 0% 0 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

I'm new to squid and not sure if I should create a `external_acl_type` directive or if somehow the credentials are being cached. Any help would be much appreciated.